# Error with dynamically adding worksheets to workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i have a code that loops through a range of cells and for each name in that range it will add a new sheet and name the new sheet after whatever is in the cell. the line of code "ws.Name = Employee_name" is giving me a 1004 runtime error "Application-Defined or Object-Defined error" it is only giving this error the second time through the look it is able to rename the sheet for the first loop. any ideas on how to prevent this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub read_WFH_dockets()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Employee_name As String
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

Dim Rng_Employees As Range
Dim EmployeeFAB
Dim numrows As Long
Dim Fab As String


numrows = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng_Employees = Range("B1:B" & numrows)

For Each EmployeeFAB In Rng_Employees.Cells

    Employee_name = Range("A" & EmployeeFAB.Row)
    Fab = EmployeeFAB.Value

    Set ws = WB.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = Employee_name

    Set ws = Nothing
    Employee_name = ""
    Fab = ""

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Then `Employee_name` is not a valid worksheet name. What is its value?

Comment: @BigBen i have row A:A s values as 1,2,3,4 just for testing but i also tried it with "Jacob1", "Jacob2", "Jacob3", "Jacob4"

Comment: `Employee_name = EmployeeFAB.Offset(,-1).Value`. Your problem likely is that `Range("A" & EmployeeFAB.Row)` refers to the active sheet.

Comment: @BigBen Worked Splendidly thank you.

Comment: For reference, whenever you create a fresh new Sheet, this sheet becomes the Active sheet, and if you try to use Range, or Cells without referencing a sheet name then you are referencing the newly created Sheet. The code was trying to use an Empty cell for the name. BigBen used `EmployeeFAB.` to reference the original Sheet/Range and got the correct Cells this way.

Comment: @RicardoA yes. thank you both for the help!